# How to set sprite/GIF image with video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

I have working on set sprite/animated image on video but can't understand that how to do this. some one please help me to suggest how to set sprite image with video.

Comment: What do you mean by "set sprite image with video"? create a sprite (i.e  image sequence) from a video?

Comment: As I discribe in my question I wand to create something like play video with rain fall effect or love fall or something like fall dollar from sky want to merge this type of image/GIF with video so please suggest me.

Comment: Why down vote I can't Understand.. if some one know the answer then please post answer wats wrong in this question ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What are these "sprites"?  Are you using SpriteKit?  Are you just trying to play a video?  Is the video going to be in the background or is it going to be moving around or is it the only thing on screen?  How is your code and project set up right now?

Comment: I  want to set some animated image/GIF/sprite on existing video, combine it and create new video. No I am not used sprite kit. my project is not game application its just about video effects/filters.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with programming?

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is convert your "gif" animation to a video, and then mix it with other videos like any other normal occasion.

Comment: But how to create transparent video ?